# How determine Helm Server version

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm sorry if it is noob question, but I can't find an explanation for this anywhere.

I need to know which version of the helm server are running on the cluster. In my machine I have the helm client in both versions (helm2 and helm3), when I run the command `helm2 version` or `helm3 version`, I'm not sure if I am getting the client or the server version.

For example, on kubectl it describes both client and server version:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.7", GitCommit:"0c38c362511b20a098d7cd855f1314dad92c2780", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-20T10:09:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.4", GitCommit:"bf9a868e8ea3d3a8fa53
```

What could be the best way to determine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

helm3 does not have a server version unlike helm v2.

You can run `helm version` for helm v2.

Here is the [tiller removal doc](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/#removal-of-tiller).